# compare buffer with const char* in C++

Tags: c++, string, comparison

What is the correct C++ way of comparing a memory buffer with a constant string - `strcmp(buf, "sometext")` ? I want to avoid unnecessary memory copying as the result of creating temporary std::string objects.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post some code using std::string that illustrates what you are asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just checking for equality, you may be able to use [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal)

```
#include <algorithms>

const char* text = "sometext";
const int len = 8; // length of text

if (std::equal(text, text+len, buf)) ...
```

of course this will need additional logic if your buffer can be smaller than the text

Answer (score 4):

strcmp is good if you know the contents of your buffer. [`std::strncmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncmp) might give you a little more security against buffer overflows.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` works fine, no copy is made. Alternatively, you could also use [`memcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcmp/). However, when in C++, why not use `std::string`s?

Comment: If I convert buf to std::string buffer content will be copied into string object - I want to avoid since after comparison I have nothing to do with it.

Comment: strncmp is slightly safer, but you have to make sure to put the correct value in for 'n'. Alternately, if you know that the buffer is longer than the constant string you are comparing to, then strcmp is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would use memcmp, and as the last parameter, use the minimum of the 2 sizes of data.

Also check to make sure those 2 sizes are the same, or else you are simply comparing the prefix of the shortest one.

Comment: His data isn't in a string yet - he's trying to avoid putting it in one.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like,

```
const char* const CONST_STRING = "sometext";

strcmp(buf,CONST_STRING);
```

Comment: From the all answers above I understand that C++/STL has no tools to make such a comparison and one must use simple C approach?